# call javascript function in php and pass php variables?

Tags: php, javascript

Say I have 3 variables, id, name, number, on a php script, $name, $number, $id

On the PHP, I create a button

```
    print "<td><form><input type='button' name='edit' id='edit' onclick=ed($name, $number, $id) value='Edit' /></td>";
```

I want those 3 variables sent to my javascript.

The function call seems to work just fine if I use

```
onclick=ed(this.id)
```

and modify the function header, and this passes the string "edit" but that's not quite useful.

function header in javascript is

```
function ed(name, number, id) {
//stuff here
}
```

For whatever it's worth using this code gets me an error on the html, something about an unexpected } on line2 of the html document.

Edit:I should clarify I said that code gives me errors so someone didn't just say "Well use this!" when I already expected it not to work.

Using this:

```
<input type='button' id='$id' onclick=ed(this.id) value='Edit' />
```

Allows me to send the value in $id to the javascript function because it was saved in the id field. Something along those lines is what I'm hoping for, but I'm unable to find if there's any way to do that. edit: for 3 variables.

Edit again:

Using:

```
<form><input type='button' name='$name' id='$id' title='$number' onclick='ed(this.name,this.title,this.id)' value='Edit' /></form>
```

sent the values of all 3 php variables to the javascript function.

It's not pretty, but it works.

Comment: You need to understand the difference between client and server side scripting

Comment: your `form` tag isn't closed

Comment: I fully understand the difference between client and server-side scripting, but thanks for the help. I was hoping someone could suggest to me a method of storing the variables for sending via javascript. For instance, setting `id='$id'` on the button then sending `this.id` is sending the value of the php variable `$id` to the javascript function. I was hoping someone had a recommendation that would allow me to send all 3.

Comment: also you need to quote `'ed($name, $number, $id)'` in the javascript

Comment: and if you want to send variables to your javascript with php, my preference is to have one variable defined in a script tag in the head, that has all of the variables as an object `echo 'var serverVars = '.json_encode(array("id"=>$id ... ));`

Comment: Your bottom edit is your own answer. Please do not add answers within your question body, but write your own answer. This if fine. Also, there is no need to mark your edits, if someone wants to know what was edited, he can look up the history.

Comment: I didn't really mean to have said I answered it myself, but rather I had figured out something that worked but not very well. I didn't know custom data-attributes existed, and coming back to this I chose that as my answer. I didn't like arbitrarily sticking data into random html fields for no reason, which was the gist of my question, I just worded it awfully, but thank you for the etiquette lesson (and I don't mean that sarcastically). In the end I wound up concatenating all 3 variables into one string and setting it as name and then breaking it apart in the js, which is still kinda ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For custom attributes define `data-attributes`, e.g. as shown on [Mozilla Dev](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.dataset):

```
<div id="user" data-id="1234567890" data-user="johndoe" data-date-of-birth>John Doe
</div>

var el = document.querySelector('#user');

// el.id == 'user'
// el.dataset.id === '1234567890'
// el.dataset.user === 'johndoe'
// el.dataset.dateOfBirth === ''

el.dataset.dateOfBirth = '1960-10-03'; // set the DOB.

// 'someDataAttr' in el.dataset === false

el.dataset.someDataAttr = 'mydata';
// 'someDataAttr' in el.dataset === true
```

In your case, it seems you only need `data-number` as the other two are standard properties of the DOM-element.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your quotes so try this

```
    print '<td><form><input type="button" name="edit" id="edit" onclick=ed('.$name.','.$number.','.$id.') value="Edit" /></td>'
```

Comment: I should've proofread my question more, but it's late. -_-; The problem isn't the code (though that was the problem, it's been fixed.) the problem is you can't literally do it the way I typed it. I meant it more as a psuedo-code.

Answer (score 0):

You can only send 3 value like this:-

```
onclick="javascript:func_name('<?php echo $var1 . "," . $var2 . "," . $var3;?>');
```

In the js function take only one argument and then split 3 values using "," as a delimiter.